# java / android NullPointerException thrown on a String

Tags: java, android, string, debugging, nullpointerexception

I have what seems like a very simple method, written in java for an android application:

EDIT 1: 
    private String newResponse;

```
public SOME METHOD CALLED FIRST
{
    newResponse = "";
}
```

END OF EDIT 1

```
public synchronized void reportMessage(String message)
{
    try
    {
        newResponse = newResponse + message;

        confirmQE(); //Look for qe in the message
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        response = e.getCause().toString();
    }
}
```

When I run the application in debugger mode, it 'suspends' on the line:

```
newResponse = newResponse + message;
```

It says in the debug window:

**Thread[<9> Thread-10] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))**

This occurs only some of the time. Sometimes it runs the line fine.

It never goes into the catch clause and when you click continue, the app crashes. There isn't a break point on the line so I don't even know why it is suspending there.

newResponse is of type String, defined as a global variable.

Can anyone help?

Comment: is newResponse is initialize at global level ??

Comment: what is the value of newResponse and message when the application crashes?

Comment: are you creating string  as "String newResponse" if yes, than you have to initialized to "String newResponse=''" . I hope it will work

Comment: Sorry @AndroidCoader, I forgot to add code that occurs earlier. I think what I have is sufficient to initialise it correctly.

Comment: @ftom2 The value of newResponse is "" and the value of message is ÌÌÌÎfffffs3333ÌÌÌÍÌÌÌÌæffs3333Æs33ÌÌÍ³33æfs333Ì³33æ..... (1024 characters long) which looks weird but is what it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem.

For anyone wondering, I added

```
if("".equals(newResponse))
{ 
    newResponse = new String();
}
```

before

```
newResponse = newResponse + message;
```

And that prevents the error.

Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 5):

```
try
    {
        // NOW add following condition and initialize newResponce only when it is null
        if(null == newResponse)
        {
            newResponse = new String();
        }
        System.out.println("newResponse"+newResponse);  //<--Add this two lines
        System.out.println("message"+message); // and check which line gives you NullPointerException

        newResponse = newResponse + message;

        confirmQE(); //Look for qe in the message
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't seem to help. I have added what you suggested but I think my initialisation that I have already was sufficient, see edit 1 in code.

Comment: See your question. I HAVE EDITED IT and try that then say.

Comment: I can't have newResponse initialised in that method as sometimes newResponse = "actual text" before the method is run. WHen I add System.out.println(newResponse); and System.out.println(message) in before newResponse = newResponse + message;, it is suspended on System.out.println(newResponse);

Comment: and some time you **don't initialize newResponse** with any text ?? Am I right? So that time you are getting NullPointerException.

Comment: yes, sometimes newResponse = "". But I want it just just = blank not equal null

Comment: Hey I have **edited my ANSWER** before 10-12 minutes **TRY IT Now, IT WILL SURE  WORK  FOR  YOU.**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14281/discussion-between-chintan-raghwani-and-pippa-rose-smith)

Answer (score 2):

```
public synchronized void reportMessage(String message)
{
    try
    {
        if(newResponse == null){
            newResponse = message;
        }else{
            newResponse = newResponse + message;
        }

        confirmQE(); //Look for qe in the message
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        response = e.getCause().toString();
    }
}
```

Try above code..

Comment: Now it is doing the same thing on the line: if(newResponse == null){

Comment: try if(newResponse.equals(null)){

Comment: `if (newResponse == null)` should not cause a NullPointerException.  In fact, that is one of the very few legit ways to check whether a reference is null.

Comment: yes, that's what I think. Still we can check other way by using if(newResponse.equals(null))

Comment: Nope, still the same. And I tried putting "" instead of null in both cases as well.

Comment: `newResponse.equals(null)` will break if `newResponse` is null, as there's no object to call `equals` on.  *That* would cause a NullPointerException.

Comment: newResponse always seems to be "" not null as such

Comment: if newResponse is ""(blank string) then it should not throw NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the individual variables to see which one is null.

Also, `e.getCause()` may be returning null also, so you may have an exception inside your exception handler as well.

Comment: Neither appears to be null.

newResponse = "" but that should be al-right shouldn't it?